# calculated column based on Next value in other column in Spotfire

Tags: function, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am trying to create a desired_B and desired_C columns which would be based on value of next row in another column. I have intersect as well.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
patient_ID column_A    desired_B     desired_C      Rank
1              27            28          NA           1
1              28            29          28-27        2
1              29            29          29-28        3
1              29            31          29-29        4
1              31            NA          31-29        5  
2              16            20          NA           1
2              20            21          20-16        2
2              21            22          21-20        3
2              22            NA          22-21        4
```

For now my code is:

```
Last([column_A]) over (
    Intersect([patient_ID],Next([Rank])))
```

Which doesn't really go in direction I want to take this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
concatenate(case  when first([column_A]) OVER (Intersect(previous([Rank]),[patient_ID])) is not null then [column_A] &"-" else "NA" end,first([column_A]) OVER (Intersect(previous([Rank]),[patient_ID])))
```

using the case statement because it otherwise returns values from Col A where we want them to be empty.

[result in spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH4G5.png)

Answer (score 0):

A more compact expression, giving the same result, would be:

`SN([column_A] & "-" & First([column_A]) OVER (Intersect(Previous([Rank]),[patient_ID])),"NA")`

It generates the "NA" when the over() statement cannot evaluate (thus resulting in value null).